# CocoaPods: point to a branch in pod spec

Tags: ios, git, cocoa, cocoapods, podspec

I'm trying to install code from a repository's branch on a pod spec, and based on the documentation, this should work:

```
s.dependency 'repository_name',
:git => 'https://github.com/account_name/repository_name.git',
:branch => 'experimental_branch'
```

But I get an error with something like **[!] Unsupported version requirements. Updating CocoaPods might fix the issue.**

It works when installing from a pod file directly:

```
pod 'ObjectiveRecord', :git => 'https://github.com/supermarin/ObjectiveRecord.git', :branch => '2-0-experimental'
```

Does anyone know? Thanks!

Answer (score 53):

You can't use a pod dependency like that, it only supports `"name", "version"`. [Source: guides.cocoapods.org](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#dependency). It is expected that the `:git` and `:branch` metadata will come from the podfile.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I was pushing the limits of cocoapods ;)

Comment: The response should be accepted as valid if it helped you.

Comment: This answer appears to be outdated. Since it's coming up on Google, would you mind updating it?

Comment: Doesn't look like it, go through to the link I posted, it's still just those two options.

Answer (score -1):

Please check the discussion here - [Link](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/262)

I think it is possible now as per the discussion but initially -

They suggested **Tag** instead of the **branch** as the problem with a branch vs a tag is that a branch does not specify a specific point in the history, whereas a tag does. This distinction is very important, as we need to guarantee that depending on a specific version of the library will result in using the same source every time. 
Technically it is possible to delete a tag and create it again pointing to a different commit, but this is less likely to happen.