# Migrate my pod to Swift 4

Tags: swift, cocoapods, swift4

I created my pod in Swift 3 and now I wanna migrate it to Swift 4.

I've already done the code migration in the Example project (I chose to create an example when running `pod lib create`), but my podspec is still not passing validation.

One of the reasons is that the default cocoapods configuration is compiling it as Swift 3.

The other is that in order to update the dependencies to compile with Swift 4, I need to reference a specific branch, like `RxSwift`, but I couldn't find a way to do that in the podspec.

How can I fix those problems?

Comment: See http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-1.1.0/ about swift version. The simplest way is to create a `.swift-version` file with `4.0` as contents.

Comment: Specifying a branch for a dependency should work the same as specifying it in a podfile, see https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#pod.

Comment: @Sulthan I'm not sure I understood, there is no `pod` declaration in the podspec

Comment: The `dependency` declaration should have the same syntax as the`pod` expression.

Comment: it doesn't. `[!] Invalid `SwiftUtilities.podspec` file: [!] Unsupported version requirements`, `>          subspec.dependency 'RxSwift', '~> 3.0', branch: 'rxswift4.0-swift4.0'`

Comment: You cannot set both `:branch` and version `3.0`. You are also missing `:`.

Comment: But you are right, it's not possible, see https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/issues/3901

Comment: Post your podfile code here please.

Comment: There is no podfile, I'm creating a pod, not importing one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [CocoaPods: point to a branch in pod spec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25140362/cocoapods-point-to-a-branch-in-pod-spec)

You can't use :git and :branch metadata in podspec. It is expected that the :git and :branch metadata will come from the podfile.

If you want to use tags then use like below : RxCocoa/RxSwift for swift 4 tag(`4.0.0-beta.0`)

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
    ###Your code here
    s.dependency 'RxCocoa', '~> 4.0.0-beta.0'
    s.dependency 'RxSwift', '~> 4.0.0-beta.0'
end
```

If you want to use branch, then
Your `podspec`is like below :

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
    ###Your code here
    s.dependency 'RxSwift'
end
```

Your `Podfile` will be :

```
use_frameworks!

target 'YOUR_TARGET' do
    pod 'RxSwift', :git => 'https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift.git', :branch => 'rxswift4.0-swift4.0'
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, where do I put the `Podfile`? I've never seen a pod with a `Podfile`. The only place I've seen a `Podfile` is in the project that is importing the pods.

Comment: In your project Podfile you have to call the `RxSwift` with branch name.

Comment: I don't have a `Podfile` in the pod project (the project that creates the pod)

Comment: Here is my pod: https://github.com/rodrigoruiz/SwiftUtilities. Ignore the `Example` folder.

Comment: You wrote like this right "The only place I've seen a Podfile is in the project that is importing the pods.". In this file you have to write.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand you correctly, but I'm not creating a project using pods, I'm creating a pod, so I'm not the one specifying stuff in a `Podfile`. In other words, the user of my pod won't even know he's using `RxSwift`, he will only import my `SwiftUtilities` pod and nothing else.

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: Thank you. I still didn't understand the `Podfile` part of your answer, but placing the tag there worked! I also needed the `.swift-version`, just for the record, in case someone else look at this answer.